# Cannot log in to CF

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I'm experiencing some problem with using the cf command line. The password works for logging in to bluemix.net web page but not in cf command line. What is wrong?

```
 $ cf login 
 API endpoint> https://api.ng.bluemix.net
 Email> xxxxxx@gmail.com
 Password> Authenticating... Credentials were rejected, please try again.
 Password> Authenticating... Credentials were rejected, please try again.
```

Comment: Which version of the `cf` binary?

Comment: @user4826201 could you try logging into http://bluemix.net?  If you can't login there could you try resetting your password at https://www.ibm.com/account/profile?page=forgot&okurl=www-947.ibm.com%2FFIM%2Fsps%2FIBM_WWW_SAML20_EXTERNAL%2Fsaml20%2Flogininitial%3FRequestBinding%3DHTTPPost%26ResponseBinding%3DHTTPPost%26NameIdFormat%3DEmail%26PartnerId%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fidaas.ng.bluemix.net%2Fsps%2Fsaml20sp%2Fsaml20&failurl=https%3A%2F%2Fidaas.ng.bluemix.net%2Fidaas%2Fpublic%2Ftamlogin.jsp&cancelurl=https%3A%2F%2Fidaas.ng.bluemix.net%2Fidaas%2Fpublic%2Ftamlogin.jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a Cygwin terminal? Try installing CF tool on your Window workstation directly if you are. There is a known issue with running CF using Cygwin.

Comment: For reference, the known issue of running cf under Cygwin is documented at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/171 and the issue was closed with the rationale that "_Cygwin is not supported currently_".  One user commented "I currently work around this issue using `cf auth login pwd` instead of `cf login`", so you may want to try that if you really want to stick with cygwin.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thanks CharlesL and jimmc!

Answer (score 1):

I may be replying to very old post but it may help someone.

When using `cf login` in Cygwin or `git bash` provide username and password in the same command like below.

```
cf login [-a API_URL] [-u USERNAME] [-p PASSWORD]
```

This way you can login to PCF.

Answer (score 1):

If using Cygwin or Git Bash, you can add `winpty` before the command to make it work:

```
winpty cf login
```

And you can create an alias in your bash startup script to avoid typing `winpty` every time:

```
alias cf='winpty cf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are using Git Bash under Windows OS, it is a known issue. Suggest to use cmd.exe instead.

Answer (score -2):

Try logging into UI at http://bluemix.net first. If that doesn't work you probably need to reset your password

Comment: This seems unlikely to be the problem.  The original post states that the password works for logging in to bluemix.net web page.

Comment: +1 to jimmc
I'm able to log in via the bluemix.net webpage so it's not about a wrong password.

Comment: Hmm, it should let you in if you are using your same username and password.  If you are 100% sure that you are and it still isn't working please send an email to id@bluemix.net and the support team can investigate your account.